# convert MAX function to WorksheetFunction.Max for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I write the formula

```
=MAX((B2:B12)*(D2:D12<>"SYSTEM")*(D2:D12<>"VOID"))
```

in Application.WorksheetFunction.Max method for VBA?

I initially wanted to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Maxifs for

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B12,D2:D12,"<>SYSTEM",D2:D12,"<>VOID")
```

but couldn't find a way to write it

Comment: I don't know any way of getting the first version of the formula to work in VBA without using a loop, but others may have better knowledge than me.

Comment: You can do e.g. `Dim MaxValue As Double: MaxValue = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MAX((B2:B12)*(D2:D12<>""SYSTEM"")*(D2:D12<>""VOID""))")`.

Answer (score 1):

The MAXIFS function should work, try it in this format:

```
WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(Range("B2:B12"), Range("D2:D12"), "<>SYSTEM", Range("D2:D12"), "<>VOID")
```