# How to code =MATCH(1,(A:A=J1)*(B:B=K1)*(C:C=L1),0) in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, match

From: [Find the ROW number in excel with multiple matching criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488091/find-the-row-number-in-excel-with-multiple-matching-criteria)
"If you need to match more than one column value to retrieve a row number, that is, if two or more columns together create a unique ID you can use an array formula with MATCH as below:

```
MATCH(1,(A:A=J1)*(B:B=K1)*(C:C=L1),0)
```

where A, B, C contain the column array to be matched to retrieve the unique row number corresponding to the value in J1, K1, L1 respectively.

For a step-by-step guide, Christian Pedersen's Explainer"

It works in a sheet as an Excel formula. How do I code it for my purposes in Excel VBA?

I tried:

```vb
Dim var As Variant
 
Sheets("MySheet").Select

'Use "1234567" is double quotes
'var = WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Range("D:D") = "1234567") * (Range("F:F") = "Text Here"), 0)

'Use 1234567 without the quotes
var = WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Range("D:D") = 1234567) * (Range("F:F") = "Text Here"), 0)
```

I removed the comment mark and tried each way independently.

The result is the same for both:

> Run-time error '13':
> Type mismatch

Comment: Perhaps similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748554/convert-max-function-to-worksheetfunction-max-for-vba it can't be translated directly into VBA as you would hope but there is a workaround using Evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As String, res
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
    
    f = "MATCH(1,(D:D=<num>)*(F:F=""<txt>""),0)"
    
    f = Replace(f, "<num>", 1234)
    f = Replace(f, "<txt>", "Text here")
    
    res = ws.Evaluate(f)  'evaluate in context of sheet `ws`
    
    If Not IsError(res) Then
        Debug.Print "matched row " & res
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Note your formula needs quotes around the value if the column type is not numeric...